# Django 1.10.3 connecting to MySQL 5.7.16

Tags: python, django, windows

Environment: Windows 8

I am trying to connect to MySQL using Django. I understand that this module is needed: 'MySQLdb'. To get this module I used `pip install MYSQL-python` and `easy_install MySQL-Python`. But I am getting the follwing error:

[image]

How can I install MySQL support for Python on Windows?

Comment: Post the error that you are getting and I think there would be a solution to it as it seems like a common problem.

Comment: Please post errors as text, not screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

`pip install` often involves building libraries from scratch. When a library includes C code that sometimes means that you need to have header files available.

While it is possible to install Python libraries this way on Windows it can involve quite a bit of setup. The last time I worked with Python on Windows I ended up using precompiled libraries from [Christoph Gohlke's website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). I recommend starting there.

Christoph provides both [`mysql-python`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python) and [`mysqlclient`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) (a fork of `mysql-python` that supports Python 3).