# Installing mysqlclient on Windows with cygwin for django serevr fails on gcc error

Tags: python, mysql, django, gcc, cygwin

I really hope someone can help me. I'm trying to install a Django server on a Windows 10 machine using cygwin.

So far I managed to get the test serevr running, and I want to hook it up to a MySql server instance running **on the Windows machine**. Since I'm using Python3 I need the mysqlclient driver, as stated in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers)

I tried installing it using pip, but I get a gcc error:

```
$ pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.9.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysqlclient: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysqlclient: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-r0034q8_/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpv8u4dfwopip-wheel- --python-tag cp34:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4
  creating build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python3/python3-3.4.5-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python3-3.4.5-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python3/python3-3.4.5-1.x86_64/src/Python-3.4.5=/usr/src/debug/python3-3.4.5-1 -Dversion_info=(1,3,9,'final',1) -D__version__=1.3.9 -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/_mysql.o "-I/cygdrive/d/tweb/mysql/include/mysql" "/MT" "/Zi" "/O2" "/Ob1" "/D" "NDEBUG" "-DDBUG_OFF"
  gcc: error: "-I/cygdrive/d/tweb/mysql/include/mysql": No such file or directory
  gcc: error: "/MT": No such file or directory
  gcc: error: "/Zi": No such file or directory
  gcc: error: "/O2": No such file or directory
  gcc: error: "/Ob1": No such file or directory
  gcc: error: "/D": No such file or directory
  gcc: error: "NDEBUG": No such file or directory
  gcc: error: "-DDBUG_OFF": No such file or directory
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient: started
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-r0034q8_/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-0zo72r3z-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4
    creating build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python3/python3-3.4.5-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python3-3.4.5-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python3/python3-3.4.5-1.x86_64/src/Python-3.4.5=/usr/src/debug/python3-3.4.5-1 -Dversion_info=(1,3,9,'final',1) -D__version__=1.3.9 -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/_mysql.o "-I/cygdrive/d/tweb/mysql/include/mysql" "/MT" "/Zi" "/O2" "/Ob1" "/D" "NDEBUG" "-DDBUG_OFF"
    gcc: error: "-I/cygdrive/d/tweb/mysql/include/mysql": No such file or directory
    gcc: error: "/MT": No such file or directory
    gcc: error: "/Zi": No such file or directory
    gcc: error: "/O2": No such file or directory
    gcc: error: "/Ob1": No such file or directory
    gcc: error: "/D": No such file or directory
    gcc: error: "NDEBUG": No such file or directory
    gcc: error: "-DDBUG_OFF": No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-r0034q8_/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-0zo72r3z-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-r0034q8_/mysqlclient/
```

`D:\tweb\mysql` is where the windows MySql serevr is installed (it's a portable installation)

The environment I'm using is:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.4.5

$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)

$ python -m django --version
1.10.4

$ ls -l `which gcc`
-rwxr-xr-x 3 Stefano None 790035 13 giu  2016 /usr/bin/gcc
```

I also installed other gcc versions from the cygwin installer, here is all I have now:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/ | grep gcc
lrwxrwxrwx    1 Stefano None       7 15 dic 16.42 cc -> gcc.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 Stefano None    6707  6 gen  2010 colorgcc
-rwxr-xr-x    1 Stefano None   71187 13 giu  2016 cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll
-rwxr-xr-x    3 Stefano None  790035 13 giu  2016 gcc.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    2 Stefano None   26643 13 giu  2016 gcc-ar.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    2 Stefano None   26643 13 giu  2016 gcc-nm.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    2 Stefano None   26643 13 giu  2016 gcc-ranlib.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    2 Stefano None  731155 24 giu 23.52 i686-pc-cygwin-gcc.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    2 Stefano None  731155 24 giu 23.52 i686-pc-cygwin-gcc-5.4.0.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 Stefano None   26643 24 giu 23.52 i686-pc-cygwin-gcc-ar.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 Stefano None   26643 24 giu 23.52 i686-pc-cygwin-gcc-nm.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 Stefano None   26643 24 giu 23.52 i686-pc-cygwin-gcc-ranlib.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    3 Stefano None  790035 13 giu  2016 x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    3 Stefano None  790035 13 giu  2016 x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc-5.4.0.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    2 Stefano None   26643 13 giu  2016 x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc-ar.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    2 Stefano None   26643 13 giu  2016 x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc-nm.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    2 Stefano None   26643 13 giu  2016 x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc-ranlib.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    2 Stefano None  790547  5 nov 04.19 x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    2 Stefano None  790547  5 nov 04.19 x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-5.4.0.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 Stefano None   26643  5 nov 04.19 x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-ar.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 Stefano None   26643  5 nov 04.19 x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-nm.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 Stefano None   26643  5 nov 04.19 x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-ranlib.exe
```

I tried to use the other gcc versions by creating a symbolic link called `gcc` in `/usr/lib` to the other `gcc.exe`s, but I always get the same the same error.

I also tried [this MinGW compiler](https://github.com/develersrl/gccwinbinaries) as suggested in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969715/gcc-failed-with-install-python-mysql-libraries-on-cygwin), but I get a different error (it complains about the -`Wno-unused-result` flag)

Does anyone has any idea? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT (as per Chris comment):

I tried [this "possible duplicate"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41088481/4046810) solution, but I cannot install the weehls provided on [Christoph Gohlke's website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) I think because they're not meant for cygwin. I also tried to trick pip into accepting it; here's what cygwin will accept

```
$ python
Python 3.4.5 (default, Oct 10 2016, 14:41:48)
[GCC 5.4.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pip
>>> print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())
[('cp34', 'cp34m', 'cygwin_2_6_0_x86_64'), ('cp34', 'abi3', 'cygwin_2_6_0_x86_64'), ('cp34', 'none', 'cygwin_2_6_0_x86_64'), ('cp33', 'abi3', 'cygwin_2_6_0_x86_64'), ('cp32', 'abi3', 'cygwin_2_6_0_x86_64'), ('py3', 'none', 'cygwin_2_6_0_x86_64'), ('cp34', 'none', 'any'), ('cp3', 'none', 'any'), ('py34', 'none', 'any'), ('py3', 'none', 'any'), ('py33', 'none', 'any'), ('py32', 'none', 'any'), ('py31', 'none', 'any'), ('py30', 'none', 'any')]
```

So I downloaded the file `mysqlclient‑1.3.9‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl` and renamed it into `mysqlclient‑1.3.9‑cp34‑cp34m‑cygwin_2_6_0_x86_64.whl`. It said that it was installed, so I edited my django `settings.py` to use the mysql connector:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': ...,
    'USER': ...,
    'PASSWORD': ...,
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '3306',
}
```

but django still complains about not finding the mysqldb module:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named '_mysql'
```

EDIT 2 (as per Dan-Dev comment):
I tried to install libmysqlclient-devel, now the compilation errror says:

```
building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python3/python3-3.4.5-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python3-3.4.5-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python3/python3-3.4.5-1.x86_64/src/Python-3.4.5=/usr/src/debug/python3-3.4.5-1 -Dversion_info=(1,3,9,'final',1) -D__version__=1.3.9 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-3.4/_mysql.o
    _mysql.c:40:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I guess it stopped using the windows library and used the one installed from cygwin instead. Am I missing something else? Maybe some other header?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django 1.10.3 connecting to MySQL 5.7.16](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41087806/django-1-10-3-connecting-to-mysql-5-7-16)

Comment: Can you install libmysqlclient-devel https://cygwin.com/cygwin/packages/x86/libmysqlclient-devel/ through cygwin first and retry?

Comment: @Chris thank you for pointing me at that answer, I also tried to search for the wheels but couldn't find them. Anyway using those didn't solve my problem, I edited the question with what I tried.

Comment: @Dan-Dev I tried your suggestion and added the edit2 to my question. It looks like I'm missing some other header (Python.h?)

Comment: never mind, it was easy enough XD. Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to install this package.

I followed the Dan-Dev comment above and install `libmysqlclient-devel`.
This wasn't still enough in my case, I had to install the `python-devel` package too.

I then re-issued the command:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

and it worked.

Thank you very much guys :D